# VBA User Defined Function to display 1/8th inch shows up blank

Tags: excel, vba, format, rounding, user-defined-functions

I'm very new to VBA. I wrote this UDF (my first proper bit of coding) and I'm screwing something up, but I don't know what. I know very little and am currently taking a course, but most answers seem interchangeable to my uneducated eyes.

Also, if anyone has any tips on reducing numbers of variables or cleaning up code in general, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
Function NearestEighth(number) As String
Dim NE As String

WholeNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(number, 0)
DecNum = (number) - (WholeNum)

    Near = Round(DecNum * 8, 0) / 8

Select Case Near

Case Is = 0
NE = ""

Case Is = 0.125
NE = "1/8"

Case Is = 0.25
NE = "1/4"

Case Is = 0.375
NE = "3/8"

Case Is = 0.5
NE = "1/2"

Case Is = 0.625
NE = "5/8"

Case Is = 0.75
NE = "3/4"

Case Is = 0.875
NE = "7/8"

End Select

Prelim = (number)

Select Case Prelim
    
    Case Prelim > 0 And Prelim < 1
    FractionFormat = NE
    
    Case Prelim > 1
    FractionFormat = (WholeNum) & "-" & (NE)
    
End Select

NearestEighth = FractionFormat

End Function
```

Comment: Note that `Round` uses banker's rounding, you probably want to use `WorksheetFunction.Round`.

Comment: why not just use the format `# ?/8`?  If you want the text to be the output: `= TEXT(A1,"# ?/8")` no need for vba.

Comment: It's not for my use. I have done this in Excel, but I'd like to be able to simply call the function. Also, it seems like a simple enough task and good practice for a newbie like me.

Comment: If you need a UDF: `NearestEighth = Format(number,"#\-?/?")`

Comment: @ScottCraner I tried that. It gave me some weid outputs. 0.3 yields -?/?, 0.7 got 1-?/?. I think it's just off the mark.

I tried adding the calculation separately, but got similar results.  

`Function Craner2(number)  

    Dim Near As Double  

    Near = Round(number * 8, 0) / 8  

    Craner2 = Format(number, "#\-?/?")  

End Function  
`

Comment: your mistake is using = with fractional numbers.  Change your code to use < instead. So 0 is <0.125, 1/8 is < 0.125 etc

Comment: sorry use the `Application.WorkSheetFunction.Text(number,"#\-?/?")`

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
Public Function NearestEighth(number As Double) As String
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, n8 As Double
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    
    n8 = wf.Round(number * 8, 0) / 8
    
    NearestEighth = wf.Text(n8, "# -?/8")
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Select..Case` can only be used for distinct cases, and not a continuous range.

Use `If` instead to replace `Select Case Prelim.. End Select`:

```
If Prelim > 0 And Prelim < 1 Then
    FractionFormat = NE
ElseIf Prelim > 1 Then 
    FractionFormat = (WholeNum) & "-" & (NE)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

**Write entire dataset using spill range (MS365)**

Using MS 365 you could even call a procedure to write values *all at once* using a so called spill range (e.g. `"B1#"`) to reference the dynamic target:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ShowNearestEighths()
With Sheet1                  ' referencing the project's worksheet by Code(Name)
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'calculate nearest eighths
    .Range("B1").Formula2 = "=Round(A1:A" & lastRow & " * 8, 0) / 8"
    'use spill range to format
    .Range("B1#").NumberFormat = "# -?/8"
End With
End Sub
```